# Pointing man pages to different location

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, manpage

In my environment, I am installing a different SSH server other than openSSH. When I issue a `man ssh` command, for example, I want it to point to the new ssh server man page, rather than the openssh man page. The only way I have seen to do it so far is to physically copy all the man pages from the new ssh server to the `/usr/local/man` directory. Does anyone know of an easier/cleaner way to do this, such as a configuration file to point man to look the new man entries where I would provide a directory?

Comment: You will have to copy man pages to /usr/share/man after building the ssh server with make.

Comment: `export MANPATH=/opt/your-ssh/man:$MANPATH` might do the trick.  Otherwise, check what `man man` has to say.

Comment: It is a vendor ssh server so there will be no compiling or making. Any other ideas?

Comment: One part of programming is knowing how to configure software once it is installed.  I don't see this as off-topic for SO.

Comment: This probably does belong more on Super User, but @Jonathan's point is a reasonable argument in favor of keeping it here.  I'd set `MANPATH` as above, but depending on your `man` variant, you may also be able to do `man -M /path/to/ssh/man/dir ssh`, if you don't want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Some `man` implementations will find man pages by searching for them in a location relative to the binary.  Thus if your PATH is set up so that you find program `foo` in `/wibble/woot/bin/foo`, then `man` will look for the corresponding manpage in `/wibble/woot/bin/../share/man/man1/foo.1`.

The actual path used is pretty configurable, so check the details your local `man(1)` manpage.

That search algorithm may include a reference to `$MANPATH`, so that'll give you a further way of controlling the search.